# Largest abelian subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, group-extensions

Consider a group $G$ which is generated by three element $a,\ b,\ c$, i.e. $G=
(a)\ast (b)\ast (c)$ and $(a)=(b)=(c)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Assume that $N$ is a ${\bf smallest\ normal\ subgroup}$ containing $c^3b^{-1}$. Here my question is whether $G/N$ contains a group $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as a subgroup.

Proof : $c,\ c^2b^{-1}$ commute in $G/N$.

That is $G/N$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. But I can not prove whether $G/N$ contains $\mathbb{Z}^3$. How can we prove this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $b = c^3$ in the quotient, isn't $G/N$ isomorphic to the free group on two generators?  Also, I don't think I agree that you've shown that $G/N$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  Since $c^3b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}$ in $G/N$, then $\langle a, c^3b^{-1}a^{-1} \rangle = \langle a, a^{-1} \rangle = \langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Or maybe I misunderstood your claim?

Comment: I see. I edit it.

Comment: I think the subgroup $\langle c, c^2 b^{-1} \rangle$ of $G/N$ has the same problem. In the quotient we have $b = c^3$, so $b^{-1} = c^{-3}$, so $c^2 b^{-1} = c^2 c^{-3} = c^{-1}$.  So I think $\langle c, c^2 b^{-1} \rangle = \langle c, c^{-1} \rangle = \langle c \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$, too.  If you agree that $G/N$ is isomorphic to the free group on the generators $a$ and $c$, it may be helpful to forget about $b$ and just think in terms of these two generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G/N=\langle a,b,c\mid c^3b^{-1}\rangle\cong\langle a,c\rangle$ since $b=c^3$ in the quotient.

The [Nielsen-Schreier theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem) says that every subgroup of a free group is free.  Therefore, the largest-rank abelian subgroup of $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

$G/N$ does not contain a $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  In your example, $c^2b^{-1}$ is equal to $c^{-1}$ in the quotient, so the reason $c^2b^{-1}$ and $c$ represent commuting elements in $G/N$ is that they are in the same $\mathbb{Z}$ subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for your introducing Nielsen-Schreier theorem. But I want to consider quotient of free group $G$ by free normal subgroup$N$. Hence $G/N$ may be $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in other example.

Comment: With the given $N$, the quotient is a free group on two generators. I don't understand the objection.

Comment: I do not understand the following : Largest rank abelian subgroup of $G/N$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The rank of a free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is $n$.  If $n>1$, then the free abelian group is not a free group.  $\mathbb{Z}$ is the largest-possible-rank abelian subgroup of any free group.  $G/N$ is a free group, so it does not contain a $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for $n>1$, but it does contain $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I mean : Why is $G/N$ free ?

Comment: In the first line: $G/N$ is isomorphic to a free group on two generators because $b=c^3$ in the quotient.  In other words: let $\phi:G/N\to \langle x,y\rangle$ be defined by $a\mapsto x$, $b\mapsto y^3$, $c\mapsto y$.  Since $c^3b^{-1}\mapsto y^3(y^3)^{-1}=e$, this is a homomorphism, and also a surjective homomorphism.  It has an inverse map $x\mapsto a$ and $y\mapsto c$.  It is an isomorphism.

Comment: I see. I understand the proof. Thank you for your comment.